# Озадачен странным указанием поставить запятую от Word 2003

Tags: пунктуация

> Он наклонил голову к плечу и некоторое время раздумывал о вопросе.

Word предлагает поставить запятую после `плечу`.

> Он наклонил голову к плечу, и некоторое время раздумывал о вопросе.

Но это же `и` в списке из 2х элементов `наклонил` и `раздумывал`, следовательно запятая не нужна. Ставить или не ставить?

Comment: Я бы не поставил. По моему мнению, Word не прав.

Comment: Раздумывал о вопросе — не очень по-русски звучит. Задумался,  думал.

Answer (score 1):

Не ставить и не верить автокорректу и подобного рода подсказкам безоговорочно, безусловно; это всего лишь подспорье в работе корректора, но никак не замена этой работе. В обозримом будущем это точно изменится, и на автоматизацию корректуры можно будет полагаться практически полностью, сейчас это точно не так, а в 2003 так не было и подавно.

Answer (score -1):

На мой взгляд, предложение без запятой грамматически неверно, т.к. две разные формы глагола - наклонил ( что сделал) и раздумывал (что делал). Поэтому word пытается разбить его в два предложения запятой (голову наклонил, и раздумывал (когда-неясно)).

Он наклонил голову к плечу и некоторое время пораздумывал над вопросом - правильно.

Поэтому формально - Word прав. Но только потому, что предложение неверно построено с точки зрения выбора слов.